# Remove cell in a CSV file if a certain value is there

Tags: python, list, parsing, csv, indexing

I have two types of CSV files, and I want to merge them together.
To do that, I want to locate certain values in each row and remove them if they are there.

I tried using **list.Index** or **list.Remove** functions but I get an error when the values are not in the specific file.

For example, the two rows are (I cut the rest of the rows for better display):

```
CSV 1950    1300    1180    48  48  400 2   PASS        0   51:31.5
CSV 3270    2500    1950    1300    1180                        48
```

I want to locate the cells with the values "*3270*" and "*2500*" so the two files will align...
After that I want to remove the *empty cells* so again - they will align...

Can you please help me understand the way to do this?

thanks,
Nimrod.

Comment: How are you aligning the files? Are you making the cells with `3270` and `2500` the first two and deleting everything before? Will they always be `3270` and `2500`?

Comment: Do the CSV files have a row at the top containing column names?

Comment: The first couple of rows in the files might not be the same...
The data rows are the same except for couple of cells that 1 type of file has and the other does not. - for ex. the *3270* and the other value are located in 1 type of files and not in the other

Comment: Could you provide a broader sample of the data ? Also, what's to say the the 1st line isn't missing values instead of the 2nd; as in, what determines that any given row should be "pulled" to the left or right?

Comment: Dilber, I'm not sure what is the confusion...
All I'm trying to do is to go over a row and if it HAS a value of "3270" - remove it. Is that not possible in python??

Comment: As in, only the value "3270"; context and order doesn't matter?

Comment: OK, a different question - how do I delete a CSV cell with python?
I have located the cell I want to delete - can I delete it by its cell location (ex. `list.remove[5]` will delete *cell #5*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're hoping to accomplish, but I think this ought to get you started.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv    

myfile = '/path/to/untitled.csv'
newfile = '/path/to/untitled_new.csv'

reader = csv.reader(open(myfile))

remove_me = {'3270','2500'}

print('Before:')
print(open(myfile).read())

for row in reader:
    new_row = []
    for column in row:
        if column not in remove_me:
            new_row.append(column)

    csv.writer(open(newfile,'a')).writerow(new_row)

print('\n\n')
print('After:')
print(open(newfile).read())
```

**Output:**

```
Before:
1950,1300,1180,48,48,400
3270,2500,1950,1300,1180



After:
1950,1300,1180,48,48,400 
1950,1300,1180
```

Make sure that you're not using list.remove while you're iterating over that same list, or you'll likely mess yourself up. My code above uses a safer strategy of copying the values that pass your `if` test (column is **not** one of your values that you want to get rid of) to a new list, then writing that new list to a new .csv file.

Is this more or less what you're intending to do?

To get rid of blank cells, I presume you could add `''` to `remove_me`.

Comment: I liked your way. I did the following to solve it:
`if NewRow[1]=='3270':
    del NewRow[1:3] 
    del NewRow[4:9] 
    del NewRow[6]`

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to loop each value from the file and then put some conditions deleting the elements and then merge the values into a new output file

Step1 Reading the file

```
import sys
import csv
updatedlist = []
for val in csv.reader(open('input1.csv' , 'rb')) :
    print val

## val will be a list of each row , 
## So in this case you will have to 
## select the elements while you will be looping 
## then replace or removing the elements you want to remove
## and make a new updated list which you will then have 
## to append to a new output.csv file
## then do the same the to the other file and append to the output.csv file    


for Values  in  updatedlist :

##looping thru the values and then make a string of the values separated by commas
        f  = open('output.csv' , 'a')
        f.writelines(updatestring) ##updated list with a string of comma separated values 
        f.close()
```