# How would I remove specific characters from only one column in a CSV using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to have my column be only integers, but unfortunately the CSV I need to use has the letters T and Z interspersed.

For example:

> 2022-09-24T00:30:49Z

How would I go about removing these letters for only this one column? I have tried looking elsewhere, but I can't find anything specifically relating to this.

Comment: T and Z are for time and time-zone, removing these won't make this column an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df["column"]= df["column"].replace(r"T|Z", "", regex = True)`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you, I had something similar in mind but I wasn't sure how exactly to implement.

Answer (score 2):

```
def custom_func(x):
  if isinstance(x,str):
    return x.translate(None,'TZ')
  return x
df.col = df.col.apply(custom_func)
```

You can use applymap method to apply it to each individual cell if you may

Comment: I appreciate your input, unfortunately it's saying Index has no attribute apply. Nevertheless, it has been solved and I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This question should at least get you started in the right direction: [Remove cell in a CSV file if a certain value is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804681/remove-cell-in-a-csv-file-if-a-certain-value-is-there)

Comment: I'll definitely keep this in mind if I do need to remove a cell in the future, thanks though.